# Concatenate string to column name on dynamic SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

today I was working on this table (table_1) on SQL Server :

```
Id_Escenario Tienda Trabajador Semana Horas Contrato Lunes_Turno
1 1 1 1 44 08:30-18:00
1 1 1 2 44 08:30-18:00
1 1 1 3 44 08:30-18:00
```

I want to pivot the column 'Semana' to get a table like this one:

```
id_escenario tienda trabajador horas contrato 1 2 3
1 1 1 44 08:30-18:00 08:30-18:00 08:30-18:00
```

I'm doing it on dynamic SQL so I don't have to hardcode all the weeks (Semana) by hand. The first table could have 2 or more weeks. The code I've worked so far is the following:

```
declare @sql as nvarchar(2000);declare @col as nvarchar(2000);

select @col = isnull(@col + ',', '') + quotename([Semana])
from (select distinct [Semana] from [dbo].[Resultados_Turnos_Final]) as 
tabla;

set @sql =N'

select id_escenario,tienda,trabajador,[horas contrato],' + @col +
'from (select id_escenario,tienda,trabajador,semana,[horas contrato],
[Lunes_Turno] from [dbo].[table_1]) a
pivot(max([Lunes_Turno]) for semana IN (' + @col + ')) AS pvtSemana
';

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

I wanna concatenate Monday (Lunes) to every column week from 1 to 3, to get something like this (this is the part I can't get done):

```
id_escenario tienda trabajador horas contrato Lunes_Turno_1 Lunes_Turno_2 Lunes_Turno_3
1 1 1 44 08:30-18:00 08:30-18:00 08:30-18:00
```

I wanna do this to create a SQL statement on the fly that pivots the necesary weeks and associates them with the day of the week. Sorry if some formatting is wrong I'm quite new here and thanks in advance.

Comment: MySQL isn't SQL-server so i have removed the MySQL tag because the SQL code provided clearly looks like SQL-server syntax.

Comment: I'm still interested on this question. I think I've followed the instructions on the website to make a 'Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example'. If something is missing please let me know.